# Let f be the mapping from ℚ2 to ℚ3 defined by:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems

Let
$\mathit f$
be the mapping from $\Bbb Q$$^2$ to $\Bbb Q$$^3$ defined by:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ $\rightarrow$ (x+y)$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be the canonical basis vectors of $\Bbb Q$$^3$, and let
$e'_1:= e_1, e'_2:= e_2, e'_3:= e_1 + e_2 + e_3.$

(A)  $\mathit f$($
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$) coordinated to  ($e_1, e_2, e_3$), equals $
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

(B) $\mathit f$($
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$) coordinated to ($e_1, e_2, e_3$), equals  $
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

(C) The vector from  $\Bbb Q$$^3$  with coordinates $
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$ regarding ($e_1, e_2, e_3$) is included in the image of $\mathit f$.

I think only (B) is true but could someone please explain? I understand why (A) isn't true but don't really understand (B) and (C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) is not true because
$$f(1,1)=(2,2,2)=2e_1+2e_2+2e_3,$$
so in coordinates $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$, $f(1,1)$ is $(2,2,2)$, not $(1,1,1)$.

(B) is true because
$$f(1,1)=(2,2,2)=0e_1'+0e_2'+2e_3',$$
so in coordinates $(e_1',e_2',e_3')$, $f(1,1)$ is $(0,0,2)$.

(C) is true because, for example,
$$f(1,0)=(1,1,1)=1e_1+1e_2+1e_3.$$
In fact the image of $f$ is the subspace generated by $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Why is f(1,1)=(2,2,2) I don't understand why e'1 and e'2 are multiplied by 0 while e'3 isn't?

Comment: @annnna It's just the definition of $f$: $f(1,1)=(1+1)(1,1,1)=2(1,1,1)=(2,2,2)$. Now you want to write $(2,2,2)$ as a linear combination of $e_1',e_2',e_3'$. Note $e_3'=(1,1,1)$, so $f(1,1)=(2,2,2)=2(1,1,1)=2e_3'=0e_1'+0e_2'+2e_3'$.

Comment: Thankss now I understand

Comment: @annnna You're welcome :)